# My Google Analytics have not working past one week more

Tags: google-analytics

My Google Analytics account is not working past one week more, I am trying to enter the Analytics area I dont get any message or nothing.
Just only one warning sign on top. I am put that screen shoot, please anyone tell what is the problem..? How may I recover that..?!

[Google Analytics Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9S3v.png)

Answer (score 2):

Turn off AdBlock - this help to me :)

Comment: Same with me: disabling AdBlock Plus on the domain did the trick.